# Questions relating to choosing a j-tuple (j≤n) of positive integers whose sum is at most n.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

> Let j and n be positive integers, with j ≤ n. An experiment consists of
>   choosing, at random, a j-tuple of positive integers whose sum is at most n.
>
> a) Find the size of the sample space. Hint: Consider n indistinguishable
>   balls placed in a row. Place j markers between consecutive pairs of balls,
>   with no two markers between the same pair of balls. (We also allow one
>   of the n markers to be placed at the end of the row of balls.) Show that
>   there is a 1-1 correspondence between the set of possible positions for
>   the markers and the set of j-tuples whose size we are trying to count.
>
> b) Find the probability that the j-tuple selected contains at least one 1.

For a), I thought this is basically [stars and bars theorem 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_one) and based on the hint given it seems like it is. If so, I think the sample space is of size $\binom{n-1}{j-1}$, with each value in the j-tuple in the interval [1, n-j+1] (?). However, the question says the sum is *at most* n instead of *equal* to n, I’m not sure if that’s a typo or if I’m mis-interpreting the question.

For b), I’m completely stuck. I think I need to find the probability that the j-tuples that does not contain any 1s and then find the complement?

Comment: Well, do not fix $n,$ fix some $k$ and hence it will be $$\sum _{k=0}^n\binom{k-1}{j-1},$$ use HockeyStick identity. For the second one, if no one has a $1$ then take a $1$ of every body. What are you left with?

Comment: @Phicar For the sum, how come k is taken from 0 to n and not from j to n? If I take a 1 off of everyone, I get k-j (or n-j), I'm not sure how to compute the number of ways I can distribute that amongst the j bins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i extend my comment a little. Recall that if $k>n$ then $\binom{n}{k}=0$ and so $$\sum _{k=0}^n\binom{k-1}{j-1}=\sum _{k=j}^n\binom{k-1}{j-1},$$
by the HockeyStick identity this sum equals 
$$\binom{n}{j}.$$
For the second part let's call your random tuple $\pi=(\pi_1,\cdots ,\pi_j)$ so that
$$P(\pi \text{ has at least $1$ one})=1-P(\pi \text{ has no ones})=1-P(\pi _l>1 \text{ for }1\leq l\leq j),$$
so consider $\pi '=(\pi _1-1,\cdots ,\pi _j-1)$ this is a $j-$tuple which adds up to $$\sum _{r = 1}^j\pi_r-1=k-j$$ if the original $\pi$ used to add up to $k\leq n$ hence your $\pi '$ should add up to a number less or equal to $n-j$ but there are $\binom{n-j}{j}$ such $\pi '$ partitions(we did that previously but now with $n-j$ instead of just $n$). Can you conclude?
**Edited** Ok, so in the comments you got the expression
$$\sum _{k=j}^n\binom{k-j-1}{j-1},$$ the deal is that $k=j$ is impossible because the $\pi _i>1$ hence the sum is greater than $j$ so you start with $k=j+1$ and so the sum gives $$\binom{n-j}{j}$$ and hence the probability is 
$$1-\frac{\binom{n-j}{j}}{\binom{n}{j}}.$$
You are right, if $n<2j$ this is $1$ all partitions should have at least one 1.

Comment: I followed up to the $\binom{n-j}{j}$ such $\pi '$ partitions. If we have a $\pi$ that adds up to k for every possible k in [j,n], don't we end up with $n-j+1$ number of $\pi '$s, or is $\binom{n-j}{j}$ counting something else?

Comment: You do not have one per each, you have one $\pi$ which has a sum equal to a number in between $[j,n].$ You take that particular partition and subtract $1's$ from each one and get the $\pi '.$ So, your goal is to find how many $j-$tuples could we have generated by that method. Now, that is equal to starting your problem by changing $n$ for $n-j.$

Comment: Yes. It is computed from that and the probability is correct.

Comment: Reposting deleted comment - Is the $\binom{n-j}{j}$ computed from $\sum _{k=j}^n\binom{k-j-1}{j-1}$? So the probability of getting at least one is 1 - $\frac{\binom{n-j}{j}}{\binom{n}{j}}$, which is zero for any n - j < j as there won't be enough "balls" such that every bin has at least two balls?

Comment: I actually thought I made a mistake in my previous comment, as for k = j, the term in the sum gives us $\binom{-1}{j-1}$. Is that actually correct? This is getting a little off topic now but how do we evaluate a binomial coefficient with negative numbers?

Comment: In general $$\binom{x}{k}=\frac{x^{\underline{k}}}{k!}=\frac{x(x-1)\dots (x-(k-1))}{k!}$$ is if you do $\binom{-n}{k}$ you get $$\frac{-n(-n-1)(-n-k+1)}{k!}=\frac{(-1)^k(n+k-1)^{\underline{k}}}{k!}=(-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}$$

Comment: My only confusion is that in $\sum _{k=j}^n\binom{k-j-1}{j-1}$, every $\binom{k-j-1}{j-1}$ has a negative factorial until k >= 2j. In context we want the coefficient to evaluate to 0 for k < 2j, but I don't have enough knowledge of factorials to know if that's actually true. To avoid dealing with negative factorials, is it equivalent to define the probability as 1 for n < 2j and to $1-\frac{\sum _{k=2j}^n\binom{k-j-1}{j-1}}{\binom{n}{j}}$ for n >= 2j?

Comment: I edited to explain why is not the case $k=j.$ if $k>j$ the binomial is not negative.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify, I was using the full definition of the binomial $\binom{n}{j} = \frac{n!}{j!(n-j)!}$. From this I think $\binom{k-j-1}{j-1}=\frac{(k-j-1)!}{(j-1)!(k-2j)!}$ and the k-2j term in the denominator is negative for k < 2j? Was my expression for P(at least one 1) = 1 for n < 2j and P(at least one 1) = $1-\sum _{k=2j}^n\binom{k-j-1}{j-1}$  for n >= 2j equivalent to your expression (just less compact)?

Comment: Yes. It seems equivalent.